# How to handle a video overexposure in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avcapturedevice

I'm working on a camera app, and I think the behavior of my app and the iPhone default camera app against overexposure is very different.

Like the image below, the default camera app adjusts the overexposure when it's detected. (I feel the whole screen gets slightly yellow-ish to get rid of the overexposed brightness area. So I can see the white keyboard even putting dark stuff covers most of the screen.

[image]

Here is my app and I set the exposure mode to the [continuous exposure mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/exposuremode/continuousautoexposure), but it won't adjust the overexposed area.

[image]

I want to adjust the brightness, but I also don't want to display the image including the overexposed part (I mean... I just want my app to show like the default camera does.)

This is the code for adjust the focus and exposure.

```
    func setFocus(with focusMode: AVCaptureDevice.FocusMode, with exposureMode: AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode, at point: CGPoint, monitorSubjectAreaChange: Bool, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    
    guard let captureDevice = captureDevice else { return }
    do {
        try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        completion(false)
        return
    }
    
    if captureDevice.isSmoothAutoFocusSupported, !captureDevice.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled { captureDevice.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = true }
    
    if captureDevice.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported, captureDevice.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode) {
        captureDevice.focusPointOfInterest = point
        captureDevice.focusMode = focusMode
    }
    
    if captureDevice.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported, captureDevice.isExposureModeSupported(exposureMode) {
        captureDevice.exposurePointOfInterest = point
        captureDevice.exposureMode = exposureMode
    }
    
    captureDevice.isSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = monitorSubjectAreaChange
    captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
    completion(true)
}
```

and this is how I call the function

```
func setFocusToCenter() {
    let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: cameraView.bounds.width / 2, y: cameraView.bounds.height / 2)
    let pointInCamera = cameraView.layer.captureDevicePointConverted(fromLayerPoint: center)
    
    setFocus(with: .continuousAutoFocus, with: .continuousAutoExposure, at: pointInCamera, monitorSubjectAreaChange: false, completion: { [weak self] success in
        guard let self = self, success else { return }
        // do some animation
    })
}
```

if I need to work on the camera exposure and even if I set the `ExposureMode` as `continuous auto exposure`, do I still need to handle overexposure in code?
Also, if you have experienced for adjusting the overexposure, how did you achieve that?

---

Added this part later...

I took screenshots to compare the my app camera and the native iPhone camera app.

Here is my camera app with `.continuousAutoExposure` and set the `exposurePointOfInterest` to center of the screen.

[image]

However, the native iPhone camera app wont overexposed if I shoot a dark image from the similar distance...

[image]

I think the native iPhone app is also `.continuousAutoExposure` mode until I touch the screen and adjust focus to a point.

I droped the image quality in order to paste on this post, but I don't really see the blur on the original screenshots. I configure the fps to 30 (also the native iPhone camera is also 30).

So waht could be the reason for getting this overexposure....

Comment: Have you tried inspecting what the exposureMode property actually is after setFocus is called? It might not even be setting it to continuousAutoExposure and your completion will still be called with success.

Comment: @PeterParker
Thank you for the message, Peter. 
Yeah, I just printed out the exposure mode and double-checked the exposure mode was the continuous auto focus. 

The overexposure stuff happens when I shoot a dark (so far only a black stuff) object in the middle of the screen and the outside is a lighter background, like the image I added for my question. There is no issue with continuousAutoWhiteBalance when I shoot some other color objects (like blue, green e.t.c. ) in the middle of the screen.

Comment: I saw there is a setExposureModeCustom method, but I want to change the exposure continuously, so I don't use that method. 

Also, I manually changed the exposure TargetOffset, like captureDevice.exposureTargetBias = -1.0, and it sort of fix the overexpose issue, but when I shoot a video in a dark place, setting the target bias to -1.0 is not bright enough and the screen gets completely dark. Therefore, if I want to adjust the exposure with changing the target bias value, I think I need some calculations...
Like, switching the value depending on I'm in the darker/lighter place...

Comment: But I guess setting the exposure mode to .continuousAutoExposure would handle that sort of stuff and keep adjusting the exposure... 

So, I was wondering if other developers who built the camera app using .continuous AutoExposure happen the same stuff ( I mean get overexposed only when shooting the dark object in the center...)

Comment: I placed a dark object up close, the background does get brighter, but I'm seeing the exact same behavior when I switch to the native camera app. Are you consistently getting different behavior between your app and the native camera app? Try a stricter comparison maybe, without moving the phone (since those 2 photos are a bit too different, that might be resulting in different exposure behavior)

Comment: Another thought is, are you setting the frame rate anywhere? Cuz that 2nd photo looks like it has a lower frame rate. That would explain the blur, and the overexposure.

Comment: @PeterParker I added new screenshots for what they look like on my app and the native camera app. As you mentioned, yes, the native iPhone camera get it's background or brighter area overexposed when I get really close to the dark object, but my camera start getting overexposed even I stay back a little...

Comment: Aha! I was able to reproduce the exact issue you're having when I manually set the frame rate. Try not setting `activeVideoMinFrameDuration` or `activeVideoMaxFrameDuration` and see if the exposure behavior matches the native camera app. When I set both properties to 30, and put a black object center screen, the background became way more overexposed than the native camera app. And when I don't set those properties, the exposure behavior matched the native camera app.

Comment: @PeterParker Thank you for the message! Actually, I didn't set the frame rate using activeVideoMinFrameDuration and activeVideoMaxFrameDuration. However, I just printed out what those values are now, and I've got MaxFrameDuration: CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0), MinFrameDuration: CMTime(value: 1, timescale: 30, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0). 

 I'm using a library, HaishinKit (https://github.com/shogo4405/HaishinKit.swift), and I can change the fps through NetStream captureSettings property. So I just set it to 30.

Comment: I tried fps to some other values & set nothing for the property, but I still got the same overexposed camera screen. 
btw, thank you so much for helping me out. I've been trying to solve this issue at least for a month and I'm glad for your support!!

Comment: Oh you're welcome :) I discovered something interesting. So as you may know each lens on the device has like 50 different formats to choose from. You either set a session preset and it picks a suitable format for you, or you pick a format yourself. Or HaishinKit might be doing this for you already?

Comment: Every format has a supported frame rate range, like 1-60, or 1-30. However, if you want 30fps, you should use a format that is 1-30. Then you'll see the yellowish effect you mentioned instead of overexposure. But if you want 30fps and you're using a 1-60 format, you'll see overexposure.

Comment: I tried it out and whenever I used a 1-60 format, and set the frame rate to 30, I saw a lot of overexposure behind the black object. But when I used a 1-30 format, there was no overexposure, it looked identical to the native camera app, that yellowish appearance when you bring the black object very close.

Comment: @PeterParker 
Thank you for testing out several formats and exposure, Peter.
`as you may know each lens on the device has like 50 different formats to choose from` -> is that about AVCaptureSession.Preset? HaishinKit has a property that we can select from the AVCaptureSession.Preset, and I chose AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080 since I need the 1080p quality video when it's output (also set the fps to 30). 

As you mentioned, hd1929x1080 may not suit the frame rate of 30?

Comment: When you choose a preset, it picks a format for you. Presets are a more universal abstraction that map to an appropriate format depending on the hardware. You can see all available formats for a capture device by inspecting `device.formats`, and you can inspect the current format from `device.activeFormat`. Try print out your active format and check what the frame rate range is, it's probably 1-60?

Comment: @PeterParker
Ahh, I get that. So, here is the print statement for the `device.activeFormat`. `<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x282bc0c10 'vide'/'420f' 1920x1080, { 1- 30 fps}, HRSI:4224x2376, fov:69.654, supports vis, max zoom:16.00 (upscales @2.00), AF System:2, ISO:24.0-2304.0, SS:0.000046-1.000000, supports HDR, supports wide color, supports multicam>`
Like you told me, I get the fps value, but it's 1-30...

Comment: Well that's unexpected...are you printing the active format after all configuration code? Maybe try delaying the print to a time when the camera is running, like `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { print(device.activeFormat) }` and if it shows 1-30 confirm that you're still able to reproduce the overexposure issue.

Comment: I'm on an iPhone 11 Pro, iOS 15.5 and this overexposure issue is highly reproducible for me. I'm using the back wide camera, which has 6 1080p formats (2 are 1-30fps, 4 are 1-60fps). When I use a 1-30 format I never see overexposure. When I use a 1-60 format WITHOUT setting the fps, I never see overexposure. But when I use a 1-60 format AND set the fps to 30, I always see overexposure.

Comment: Evidently this overexposure issue is caused by some weird interplay between the format being used, and the configuration you apply (ex. setting the frame rate). It could be possible there's other configurations that are causing the same issue. For example, your code sets some properties relating to focus and exposure. I'd suggest try commenting out all your configuration code, just work with their default values, until you don't see the overexposure issue. Then enable your config one line at a time until you find the culprit

Comment: Yeah, I thought we found a solution but it was not... I printed out using asyncAfter with a few seconds, but the result is pretty much the same `<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x283c51720 'vide'/'420f' 1920x1080, { 3- 30 fps}, HRSI:4224x2376, fov:65.707, supports vis, max zoom:16.00 (upscales @2.00), AF System:2, ISO:22.0-880.0, SS:0.000020-0.333333, supports HDR, supports wide color, supports multicam, supports high photo quality>` .

Comment: @PeterParker I will try the framework's default values today and see how it goes... As you said, a property would affect the exposure stuff. I'll add some comments if I find out something later. But again, thank you soooooo much for helping me out! (I wish I could work on this with you more )

Comment: You're welcome!  `AVFoundation` has these temperamental areas lol. Hope it works out!